# hasOne() with select and where condition

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have two tables:

1. **ForumPost**, with the structure:

```
+---------+---------+
|      id | message |
+---------+---------+
```

2. **ForumPostVote**, with the structure:

```
+---------+---------+---------+
|      id | post_id | user_id |
+---------+---------+---------+
```

Here are my two model classes for each:

1. **ForumPost.php**

```
class ForumPost extends Model
{
    protected $with = [
        'userVote'
    ];

    public function votes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\ForumPostVote', 'post_id', 'id');
    }

    public function userVote()
    {
        if (Auth::check())
        {
            return $this->hasOne('App\ForumPostVote', 'post_id', 'id')->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->select('id');
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

2. **ForumPostVote.php**

```
class ForumPostVote extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\ForumPost', 'id', 'post_id');
    }
}
```

As you can see, in **ForumPost.php**, I have a function `userVote()` where I try to to select the `id` from **ForumPostVote** where the user ID matches the logged in user.

When I make the request, it returns `null`. If I remove `->select('id')`, it returns the object as normal:

```
"user_vote": {
    "id": 1,
    "post_id": 1,
    "user_id": 1
}
```

If I try something like:

```
public function userVote()
{
    if (Auth::check())
    {
        $query = $this->hasOne('App\ForumPostVote', 'post_id', 'id')->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id);

        return $query->id;
    }

    return null;
}
```

If I do:

```
public function userVote()
{
    if (Auth::check())
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\ForumPostVote', 'post_id', 'id')->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->select(['id', 'post_id']);
    }

    return null;
}
```

This returns:

```
"user_vote": {
    "id": 1,
    "post_id": 1
}
```

But that's not what I want. I *only* want `id`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try:           ->select('forumPostVotes.id'); 
correct the table name if it's wrong

Comment: @OMR Unfortunately, it's still returning `null`

Answer (score 0):

if i understand you correctly, you have many to many relation between ForumPost and user ... and the pivot table is ForumPostVote

1- the forumPostVote must inherit From Pivot not from model.

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models

2- if you want to get the id of the pivot table for the current user:

```
public function userVote()
{
    if (Auth::check())
    {
$value=$this->votes()->where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->first();
if($value!=null) return $value->id;
        return value;
    }

    return null;
}
```

please note that if there is no corresponding id in ForumPostVote table the result will be null